# What is the latest stable valid linux kernel for 3.8 version?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, linux-kernel

I want to know the latest stable kernel version of 3.8. Can any one help me out for this issue? 
I browsed for this issue but I didnt get the solution

Comment: Looking down ftp://ftp.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.x/ , it seems to be 3.8.13.  But why do you want to know?  What's the underlying question, here?

Comment: Since i want to build the latest kernel instead of upgrading the operating system. thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking down ftp://ftp.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.x , it seems to be 3.8.13.

I've repeated my comment as an answer so I can warn you against this.  I **do** have production systems which use hand-built kernels, because there are compelling business reasons to use them, but they are a huge maintenance overhead.  I don't yet understand why you think you need to do this, but I can say with some certainty that it will be a lot of time and effort for you.

I don't know ubuntu's support policies, but my understanding is that as long as 12.04 is in support, you can expect to find any important fixes from later kernels back-ported into the repositories, so just doing an `apt-get upgrade` should fix any security issues.  Once the OS falls out of support, you have bigger problems than the kernel falling out of rev, and need to arrange and upgrade as a matter of priority; just keeping the kernel updated won't keep you secure.

In addition, on some Red Hat systems I've done this on in the past, it turns out that Red Hat have been pulling in technology from some **much** later kernel, and that when I compiled a vanilla kernel from a numerically-later version that the old RH one, it wasn't yet up-to-date enough to fully support the library environment of the RH glibc etc.

Comment: this is for research, but not for the production